# How to select an incomplete range of packages with apt?

Tags: debian, apt, regular-expression

Is there a simple way to select a range of packages (especially kernel related packages) for installation or removal with apt (or another tool) ?

Currently, I am trying to remove a range of old kernels with `apt remove linux-\*-4.4.0-{40..80}-\*`.

This correctly selects the packages I want to remove, but the process is immediately interrupted by errors of the form `E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-*-4.4.0-65-*'`.

Indeed, there is no package corresponding to this regexp, but I am very surprised by the fact that this leads to an error instead of a warning. After all, removing an empty set of packages is trivial !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution).  For example:

```
apt-get remove $(dpkg -l 'linux-*' | awk '/-4.4.0-([4-7][0-9]|80)-/ { print $2}')
```

Or with `dlocate` if you have it installed:

```
apt-get remove $(dlocate -k | grep -E -- '-4.4.0-([4-7][0-9]|80)-')
```

Unlike any solution involving `xargs`, command substitution does not change `apt-get`'s stdin file-descriptor, so apt-get can receive input normally (e.g. answers to debconf questions).  `xargs` gets its own input from stdin, so should not be used with interactive programs, i.e. programs that may want input from stdin.

To use `apt-get` with `xargs`, you first have to make sure it will not ask any questions, e.g.:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
dlocate -k | grep -- -4.4.0- | xargs apt-get remove -y
```

---

Note about `dlocate`: The `-k` option lists all installed kernel and dkms related packages, one per line (and `-K` does the same, but in verbose `dpkg -L` format).  I added the `-k` option to `dlocate` to enable exactly this kind of usage, but until now it never occurred to me that there should be an optional regexp argument after the `-k`, even though that is completely obvious - I've always just used it with `grep`.

The next version of `dlocate` (i.e. >= 1.08) will support `dlocate -k '-4.4.0-'` with no need to pipe the output through `grep`.

Comment: `apt list linux-\*-4.4.0-{40..80}-\* | cut -d / -f 1` gives a correct list of packages, but using it with command substitution leads to a warning from it `apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.`, and indeed, the whole `apt-get remove $(apt list linux-\*-4.4.0-{40..80}-\* | cut -d / -f 1)` fails because intermediate output by apt is parsed by apt-get. apt-get does not have a list operation.

Comment: `dlocate -k | grep -F -- -4.4.0-` gives the list of all kernel packages, not only the ones in range 40..80.

Comment: so write a regexp for grep that matches. mine was only a simple example.   `dlocate -k | grep -E -- '-4.4.0-.*([4-7][0-9]|80)-'`

Comment: removed apt-list example and replaced it with a `dpkg -l` example.  seems apt-list won't work as required with either command-substitution or xargs.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `apt list linux-\*-4.4.0-{40..80}-\*|awk -F '/' '{print $1}' |xargs apt remove` should work I would think.

Comment: using apt-get with xargs can have problems if apt-get needs to ask any questions.     generally better use command-substitution, e.g. `apt-get remove $(apt list linux-\*-4.4.0-{40..80}-\* | cut -d / -f 1)`

Comment: btw, i generally do something like `apt-get purge $(dlocate -k | grep -E '-4\.(9|10)\.')` to get rid of old kernel image and header packages.

Comment: @cas your comments put together would constitute an interesting answer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

get the list of installed packages (`linux-image`):

```
dpkg --list | grep  linux-image | awk '{print $2}' > file
```

Sort/edit your `file` , keep only the `linux-image` to be removed , then run:

```
file=$(cat file)
echo "$file"
apt remove $file
```